# SVN Server not responding

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, iptables, svn

I've been bashing my head against a wall with this one all day and I would greatly appreciate a few more eyes on the problem at hand.

We have an in-house SVN Server that contains all live and development code for our website.  Our live server can connect to this and get updates from the repository.

This was all working fine until we migrated the SVN Server from a physical machine to a vSphere VM.  Now, for some reason that continues to fathom me, we can no longer connect to the SVN Server.

The SVN Server runs CentOS 6.2, Apache and SVN 1.7.2.  SELinux is well and trully disabled and the problem remains when iptables is stopped.

Our production server does run an older version of CentOS and SVN but the same system worked previously so I don't think that this is the issue.

Of note, if I have iptables enabled, using service iptables status, I can see a single packet coming in and being accepted but the production server simply hangs on any svn command.  If I give up waiting and do a CTRL-C to break the process I get a "could not connect to server".

To me it appears to be something to do with the SVN Server rejecting external connections but I have no idea how this would happen.

Any thoughts on what I can try from here?

Thanks, Rob

Edit: Network topology
Production server sits externally to our in-house SVN server. Our IPCop (?) firewall allows connections from it (and it alone) on port 80 and passes the connection to the SVN Server.  The hardware is all pretty decent and I don't doubt that its doing its job correctly, especially as iptables is seeing the new connections.

subversion.conf (in /etc/httpd/conf.d)

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
<Location /repos>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /var/svn/repos

   <LimitExcept PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "SVN Server"
      AuthUserFile /var/svn/svn-auth
      Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:5F:C8:3A
          inet addr:172.16.0.14  Bcast:172.16.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe5f:c83a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32317 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2544036 (2.4 MiB)  TX bytes:143207 (139.8 KiB)
```

netstat -lntp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1484/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1135/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1351/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1230/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1575/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58401               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1153/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5672                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1626/qpidd
tcp        0      0 :::139                      :::*                        LISTEN      1678/smbd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1135/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      1615/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1351/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      1230/cupsd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1575/master
tcp        0      0 :::445                      :::*                        LISTEN      1678/smbd
tcp        0      0 :::56799                    :::*                        LISTEN      1153/rpc.statd
```

iptables --list -v -n (when iptables is stopped)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

iptables --list -v -n (when iptables is running, after one attempted svn connection)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 68 packets, 6561 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   19  1304 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW udp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 17 packets, 1612 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

tcpdump

```
17:08:18.455114 IP 'production server'.43255 > 'svn server'.local.http: Flags [S], seq 3200354543, win 5840, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 2011458346 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:08:18.455169 IP 'svn server'.local.http > 'production server'.43255: Flags [S.], seq 629885453, ack 3200354544, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 816478 ecr 2011449346,nop,wscale 7], length 0
17:08:19.655317 IP 'svn server'.local.http > 'production server'k.43255: Flags [S.], seq 629885453, ack 3200354544, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817679 ecr 2011449346,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Comment: Can you add some network topology to your question?  Such as: what networks the new/old system were on in relation to production and what network gear is in the mix.

Comment: What VMware NIC driver? (Try VMXNET3 if you aren't using it.)

Comment: NIC driver, what ever comes as standard with vSphere (E1000).  I'll look into VMXNET3.

Comment: NIC driver now VMXNET3, still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I think you should update your question with full details of your SVN configuration from httpd.conf, and also `ifconfig` output,  and `netstat -lntp` to some pastebin)

However if you do the following...

```
[root@workstation001 ~]# iptables --flush             <---  flush rules
[root@workstation001 ~]# iptables --list -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 17 packets, 2792 bytes)    <---  is default policy ACCEPT?
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 1004 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 


[root@workstation001 ~]# setenforce 0
setenforce: SELinux is disabled               <---  f**k off selinux
```

And you do this on **both the guest and VM host** and you still cannot connect, then the problem is not iptables, or selinux.

So you can proceed to check each stage of the problem like so....

check you can resolve the svn server hostname;

```
[root@workstation001 ~]# dig svn.somehost.co.uk +short
www.somehost.co.uk.
209.135.17.202       <---  resolved!!
```

Can you ping the IP?

```
ping 209.135.17.202
PING 209.135.17.202 (209.135.17.202) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 209.135.17.202: icmp_req=1 ttl=50 time=132 ms <---  reply!
....
```

(assuming your svn is exposed using mod_svn_dav apache module...)

Can you connect to this server on port 80;

```
[root@workstation001 ~]# telnet svn.liepaper.co.uk 80
Trying 209.135.17.202...
Connected to svn.liepaper.co.uk.          <---  connected!
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet>
```

Can you connect to the httpd server and get the server string... (you can use curl, netcat, telnet, or whatever your TCP connect tool of choice here)

```
[root@workstation001 ~]# wget -O- --server-response http://svn.liepaper.co.uk
--2012-03-20 16:16:06--  http://svn.liepaper.co.uk/
Resolving svn.liepaper.co.uk... 209.135.17.202
Connecting to svn.liepaper.co.uk|209.135.17.202|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
  Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2012 16:16:06 GMT
  Server: Apache                    <---  server header value
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Authorization Realm"
  Content-Length: 401
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Authorization failed.
```

then try the username/password like so;

```
wget -O- --server-response --user=mysvnuser --password=mokeypoke http://svn.liepaper.co.uk/projects/admin/
```

should include something like;

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

and then try the command line svn tools to see if they make the connection;

```
[root@workstation001 ~]# svn list --username=mysvnuser --password=mokeypoke http://svn.liepaper.co.uk/projects/admin/
mystupidcode/
anotherwasteofcomputer/
cantprogrammefortoffee/
```

Basically if you get here svn is working, its the client tools or the proxy that are misconfigured....etc...

One thing to consider is that proxies mess with headers, and also that Windows 7 doesn't like Basic Auth, so you might need to implement digest authentication, or some self signed SSL to bypass either your VM, or some proxy, or windoze network work for bef**kering your svn connections. (dont try any of this until you know what the problem is...)

---

also, all the hits on the REJECT rule suggest that you might not even being trying to connect to SVN on port 80 anyway.

```
 8    26840 2356K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Stick in another rule with a LOG line before that to dump those packets to syslog;

```
itpables  -A INPUT 8 -j LOG --log-prefix "LOGDROP: "
```

change the "8" to whatever the correct rule number for your INPUT chain.... then look in /var/log for kern.log or whatever log file your syslog is configured to send iptables logging to. (it should be obvious because its going to get massive quickly)

Comment: OK, I've flushed the iptables. I've skipped the dig command as I connect directly to an IP address. I've got as far as the telnet connection and this is the stumbling block. It simply says Trying ###.###.###.### and then nothing more. Equally the wget gets as far as "Connecting to ....." and then hangs.  The thing I don't understand is the lack of error message, no timeout, no connection failed, nothing.  Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: if you wait long enough, it will timeout. It means that somewhere the packets are being dropped by a firewall, rather than REJECTed. Check your default iptables policy is not "DROP"

Comment: you can ping the IP address, yes?

Comment: iptables is disabled though, surely that wouldn't still be dropping stuff would it?

Comment: Ping is irrelevant as its not forwarded onto this machine.

Comment: Great answer. This is the approach that I try and take when troubleshooting a problem... take it step by step until you find where it's failing. And I think i just learned a new word from your last sentence.

Comment: @Rob iptables is just the front end for the netfilter kernel module. so you can't really disable it without unloading the kernel module. do `iptables --list -v -n` and past the output. although it looks like "ACCEPT" is the default. HOwever you need to check both the host and the guest

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, your web server is using a Public IP address and is outside of your LAN, correct? When it connects IN to the subversion server, how is it doing it? VPN? Is the SVN server in a DMZ? NAT? And whatever it is, can you confirm that that step is working? If you run tcpdump on the subversion server, do you even see any packets coming in at all from the web server?

Comment: Also, the behaviour you are seeing which is TCP timeout, is not consistent with the final rule you posted in your question which has "reject-with icmp-host-prohibited" which would immediately return the telnet command and not timeout like you report. Hence there is some other problem. You should re-enable ICMP for troubleshooting purposes, because at the moment there is no way to confirm your basic networking.

Comment: I don't suspect that this is the issue.  That part of the system was working just fine until we moved machines.  I've tried having the new server with the ip address of the old server and still exactly the same problems.  It can connect in because we have port 80 open to connections from the ip address of our production server.  I'll have a look at tcpdump and see what I can find.

Comment: And another thing, under 'normal' conditions, would you have httpd listening on port 80 for IPv4 to host subversion? Because you don't right now.

Comment: I've removed the reject-with rules (to be hones I'm not entirely sure what icmp-host-prohibited means), iptables --list -v -n updated as above.

Comment: @Safado, I'm not entirely I understand your last point. In netstat there's an entry for httpd on port 80. Furthermore, if in a browser I goto the local ip address version of the svn server then I get access to the SVN repository as I would expect.

Comment: I think that change has just opened the iptables completely. I don't think this is SVN or iptables related, its most likely basic networking. If you can't telnet to the port, and you can't ping the server, then iptables is not an issue.

Comment: icmp-host-prohibited is the message (probably the icmp sub type), however you don't get this message, as your telnet connection times out. So either you are not hitting that rule, or your client is also dropping the icmp reply.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with the output of tcp dump but I've added in what I think relates to the matter at hand.  Is this showing that the packet is being received but the ack is never getting back to the other server?

Comment: I've added in a line in iptables to log what's being dropped and I can't see anything to do with the relevant IP addresses.

Comment: I've got to head home now but thank you both sincerely for your help this afternoon, its been invaluable. Looks like I'm going to continue banging my head against the wall tomorrow.

Comment: so its not a problem with the svn server, the SVN server sees the SYN packet and replies; `17:08:19.655317 IP 'svn server'.local.http > 'production server'k.43255: Flags [S.], seq 629885453, ack 3200354544, win 14480, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817679 ecr 2011449346,nop,wscale 7], length 0` however the resend again, indicates this packet is being dropped somewhere. According to your iptables output, this is not by the VM guest, hence this is some basic networking or iptables setup on the VM host, or on the client

Comment: I bet you 20 quid its some problem in the vSphere Vm setup.

Comment: Side note - after all real problems, you have to fix '<Limit>' container, it must have **only** `Require valid-user`

Comment: Legendary! Thanks Tom, you have been an absolute hero.  Why on earth I hadn't thought to look at the VM settings before is mystery.  It looks like that although the VM had the correct gateway set the vSphere Server had a different (but valid) gateway.  Essentially a packet was coming in on 1 IP and then going out on a different IP.  I'm guessing that just confused the whole issue.  Thanks for all of your help debugging this.

Comment: you know I just love those upvotes!